# JMenuItem ActionListener triggers multiple ActionEvents when clicked repeatedly

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, actionevent

I am using JTables with mysql.  In the GUI I have some jmenus and jbuttons.  I have a JMenuItem with an ActionListener:

```
public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {

    bar = new JMenuBar();       
    bar.add(fileMenu);

    add = new JMenuItem("Add Customer");
    fileMenu.add(add);
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table_HALE_ACCOUNTS == null)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "First Load from Database"); 
            else {
                displayAccountsTable();
                addCustomerContainer();
                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
                }   
            }
        });
return bar;
}   

private void displayAccountsTable() {
    if (contentPane != null) {
        contentPane.removeAll();
        contentPane.revalidate();
        contentPane.repaint();
    }
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;

    contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table_HALE_ACCOUNTS), c);
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}


    public void addCustomerContainer() {
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.weightx = .25;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    contentPane.add(button_ADD_CUSTOMER, c);

    button_ADD_CUSTOMER.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String stringDeposit = textField_DEPOSIT.getText();
            double doubleDeposit = Double.parseDouble(stringDeposit);
            String stringDate = textField_DATE.getText().replaceAll("\\s", "");
            int intDate = Integer.parseInt(stringDate);

            try {   
                myAccountTableModel.insertRow(textField_NAME.getText(), textField_CUSTOMER_ID.getText(), doubleDeposit, intDate);
                textFieldSetText();  
                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }); 
    }
```

The code works fine to display a JTable and insert a row into my table model.  The problem is when I click the JMenuItem "Add Customer" multiple times.  After doing so and hitting the JButton "button_ADD_CUSTOMER" once it performs the ActionEvent insertrow for every click of the JMenuItem.  A single click of JButton will insert multiple rows instead of a single row for a single click.

Something in the ActionEvent of the JMenuItem appears to be incrementing and releasing with a single click of the JButton.

I am looking to prevent the multiple insertrows from the JMenuItem clicks, but retain the ability to hit the JButton each time I want to perform a single insertrow.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That code appears to be quite illogical.  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: The rest of the code is connecting and initializing mysql tables.  I have isolated the problem to these methods.  displayAccoutsTable doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but I included it for completeness.

Comment: *"..but I included it for completeness."*  The code in this question is still uncompilable code snippets.  Since you are either not understanding me, or not listening closely, I can help no further.  Good luck with it.

Comment: My question was primarily regarding the behavior.  I managed to work around this by moving the ActionListener of the JButton to the constructor.